# How to send png, jpg files as bot via url or from specific folder? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Well, I tried to send a picture from a specific folder but the bot can't find it. Is that me, I can't write code that would search a folder well. I would also like the bot to send images from the url.

Here is my code:

```
@commands.command()
    async def picture(self, ctx, picture):
        await ctx.send(file = discord.File(picture))
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

I'm just learning Python, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the bot on your computer or through an online software like a web interpreter?

Comment: Also, would you mind posting what errors you get when you run the command? Welcome to Stack by the way!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Bot sending file to Discord Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860397/discord-py-bot-sending-file-to-discord-channel)

Comment: I run bot on replit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need some code like this:

```
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\location\of\the\file.png'))
```

`discord.File` objects' constructor gets as first argument the `path` of the file.

---

In you case you can edit your code like this:

```
async def picture(ctx, path: str) -> None:
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(path))
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

---

If you want some more information about sending files (I read you want to send files by url too), you should write the documentation in this links:

- [Discord.py ReadTheDocs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105106/discord-py-download-image-from-link-in-message)
- [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference)